# Cannot add @angular/pwa to my angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps

Trying to add @angular/pwa by typing the command `ng add @angular/pwa` to my angular project but I keep running into this error

`✖ Unable to load package information from registry: The "timeout" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('6000000')`

I've also tried the command `ng add @angular/pwa --project <project-name>` but it also returns the same error. I've been looking high and low and can't seem to find why this is happening or how I can fix it.

I am using: 
Node: 18.16.0, 
npm: 9.7.1, 
angular-cli: 15.2.7

Thank you.